# Having trouble with fadeIn and fadeOut using jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have made a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wpC57/2) that showcases my problem.

I want the #grid-viewer to have display: none; as the page loads. Then when you hover over any of the links I want it to fadeIn and reposition accordingly.

The repositioning is working as intended now but I'm having problems with fading it in and out. It wont fade in again after it has faded out. Any help would be appreciated.

The JavaScript that handles the hovering functions looks like this;

```
$("a.mainlink").hover(function() {
    var dataTitle = $(this).attr("data-title");
    $("#grid-viewer").stop().fadeIn();
    $("#grid-viewer").stop().animate({
        "left": ($(this).offset().left - $("#grid-view").position().left)
    }, 200);
    $("#grid-text").html(dataTitle);
}, function() {
    $("#grid-viewer").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I assume it has something to do with .stop(), but I can't make it work even if I remove .stop() before fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: i see nothing in the result tab of your fiddle...

Comment: It takes a while to load....

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo oops. I forgot to save it after I changed it. Give me a sec.

edit: Try now http://jsfiddle.net/wpC57/2/

Comment: @boz I know, I forgot to change/save before sharing it. Should work now. http://jsfiddle.net/wpC57/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  maek it visible with: `$("#grid-viewer").stop().fadeIn();` but the imediatly stop the fadeIn with `$("#grid-viewer").stop().animate({` therefor the opatcity stays 0 and it is hidden.
Try includeing the fade infunctionality into your animation with like this:

```
$("#grid-viewer").stop().animate({
            "display" : "block",
            "opacity": 1,
            "left": ($(this).offset().left - $("#grid-view").position().left)
        }, 200);
```

Full sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wpC57/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.mainlink").hover(function() {
        var dataTitle = $(this).attr("data-title");
        $("#grid-viewer").show();
        $("#grid-viewer").stop().animate({
            "opacity": 1,
            "left": ($(this).offset().left - $("#grid-view").position().left)
        }, 200);
        $("#grid-text").html(dataTitle);
    }, function() {
        $("#grid-viewer").stop().fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Comment: After some more troubleshooting I found out that opacity indeed were behaving really weirdly. Why's that? Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Because the opacity is set with fadeIn and fade out to make this nice disaperance effect (it gets counted from 1, 0.9... down) and when it reacges 0 display:none is added. So if you stop the fade in animation the opaicty stays 0

Comment: No my code is working, you can't animate "display": "none", you have to use how instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the second `.stop()`, it's blocking the `fadeIn()` right after it starts.